# Should a macro used in #if be defined?

Tags: c++, c, macros

```
# if RTC

/* some code */

# endif
```

Should the macro `RTC`  be defined with a value? My compiler is not throwing an error. Do all compilers do the same? Isn't defining the macro safer?

Comment: RTC must be a valid expression. A null expression is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't have to be defined. If the identifier is undefined at the end of an `#if` expansion, it evaluates to `0`.

From ANSI C90:

> After all replacements due to macro expansion and the `defined` unary operator have been performed, all remaining identifiers are replaced with the pp-number `0`.

This, however, may not be present in compilers from before C was standardized. I once saw a GCC warning about this (I think it was on MinGW) but I can't find a source for it right now.

**Conclusion:** All standards-conformant C compilers should not throw an error upon encountering this. You do not need to define the macro before using it in `#if`.

Answer (score 6):

In a preprocessing directive such as this, if the macro is not defined, it is treated as `0`.

That is guaranteed by the language.

You can rely on there not being a compilation failure.

Here's the C++ wording:

> [`[cpp.cond]/11`](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp#cond-11): After all replacements due to macro expansion and evaluations of *defined-macro-expressions*, *has-include-expressions*, and *has-attribute-expressions* have been performed, **all remaining identifiers and keywords, except for `true` and `false`, are replaced with the *pp-number* `0`**, and then each preprocessing token is converted into a token. *[..]*

Comment: use #ifdef RTC before checking #if RTC

Comment: @TonyAbouZaidan Why?

Comment: @LightnessRaceInOrbit so you can check if its defined and not treating its value as 0 by default

Comment: @TonyAbouZaidan What will you do if it's not? If something different than the code in the question, then yes of course you need to write logic that satisfies your requirement. That's true of any part of your computer program. But it is not necessary to `#ifdef` out an `#if` check on an undeclared macro simply in order to avoid compilation failure.